# Running zookeeper on a cluster of 2 nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am currently working on trying to use zookeeper in a two node cluster. I have my own cluster formation algorithm running on the nodes based on configuration. We only need Zookeeper's distributed DB functionality.

1. Is it possible to use Zookeeper in a two node cluster ? Do you know of any solutions where this has been done ?
2. Can we still retain the zookeepers DB functionality without forming a quorum ?

Note: Fault tolerance is not the main concern in this project. If one of the nodes go down we have enough code logic to run without the zookeeper service. We use the zookeeper to share data when both the nodes are alive.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper is a coordination system which is basically used to coordinate among nodes. When writes are occurred to such a distributed system, in ordered to coordinate and agree upon values which are being stored, all the writes are gone through `master (aka leader)`. Reads can occur through any node. Zookeeper requires a master/leader to be elected per a quorum in order to serve write requests consistently. Zookeeper make use of the [ZAB protocol](https://distributedalgorithm.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/architecture-of-zab-zookeeper-atomic-broadcast-protocol/) as the consensus algorithm.

1. In order to elect a leader, a quorum should ideally have an odd number of nodes (Otherwise, a node will not be able to win majority and become the leader). In your case, with two nodes, zookeeper will not possibly be able to elect a leader for a long time since both nodes will be candidates and wait for the other node to vote for it. Even though they elect a leader, your ensemble will not work properly in network patitioning situations.
2. As I said, zookeeper is not a distributed storage. If you need to use it in a distributed manner (more than one node), it need to form a quorum.

As I see, what you need is a distributed database. Not a distributed coordination system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This makes sense to me. But when I tried faking the third device in a 2 device cluster on the zoo.cfg.dynamic file. I also set "standaloneEnabled=false" in the zoo.cfg file. This allows the two real nodes to come up and a leader is elected. I am able to perform db writes etc. Have not done enough testing to see what issues might come up. But atleast the cluster is up.

server.2=<IP1>:2888:3888:participant;0.0.0.0:2181 <<<< Fake
server.3=<IP2>:2888:3888:participant;0.0.0.0:2181
server.4=<IP3>:2888:3888:participant;0.0.0.0:2181
Do you know whats happening ?

Comment: They can come up with a leader. But the problem will occur if your network gets split, which is one of the major concerns of distributed systems. In a network split, no node will become the leader and no node will server write requests. What if you run two zookeeper instances in the same node and make the count 3?

Comment: Thank you for following up. Luckily the way run our nodes for now, there will not be a  network split. Our next option was to run multiple instances of zookeeper on the same node in case we cant make the node faking work. We are still debating which way to go. Will update this thread with the result if we go that way.

Comment: Actually a network split is not likely to happen, it's more likely that a node goes down for some reason (with me: Server patching on a regular basis by some other people). In a two node zookeeper cluster this means, that you double your chances of complete system failure, since 1 of 2 nodes is not a quorum, and everything breaks.  In that case a standalone zookeeper is actually better, since the wrong node has to be down for everything to fail, if the node goes down with no zookeeper on it, it doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: The recommended approach is to have an odd number of nodes in the quorum. Therefore you should at least have 3 nodes in your scenario.